# Show Div on Nav Element Click and Hide Other Divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, display

I built a navbar in HTML and also some Divs which are populated with a bunch of content that pertains to each nav element.

What I want to do is show the div which pertains to the selected nav element when it is clicked and hide the other divs that pertain to the other nav elements.

Basically what needs to happen is when a user clicks on a Nav Item, the class for that nav item needs to be set to 'navItem active on' in the html. Not sure if this is something that happens automatically or not.

After that, the display property defined in the CSS for the content panel of that nav item needs to be changed to 'block' and all other content panels should then have their 'display' property changed to 'none' so that they are not displayed in the page.

In the example given, I only have two content panels defined in the CSS and HTML (Capabilities and Tutorials), but each navItem will receive it's own content panel which should be toggled on when it is clicked.

I really have no idea where to begin with this. I'm pretty sure this requires JavaScript but this is literally my first attempt at building a web page and it took me 2 days even after copying a lot from another website I used for inspiration. Any help, guidance or insight is greatly appreciated.

CSS + HTML:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navItem");
for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.addEventListener('click',function(sender, event) {
        event.preventDefault();

      /* hide all panels */
        var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
        for (j = 0; j < panels.length; j++) {
            panels[j].style.display = 'none';
        }
      /* Show the selected panel */
        var panel_id = sender.target.getAttribute("panel-id");
        document.getElementById(panel_id).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```css
/* FONT ASSIGNMENTS
--------------------------- */
/* General Use */

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

p,
small {
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 35 Light', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p.large-text {
  font-size: 18px !important;
}

hr {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

.center-content {
  text-align: center !important;
}


/* Special Use */

h1,
h2,
h1 a,
h2 a,
h3,
h3 a,
infoBar,
.gisFont1,
.gisFont1 a {
  font-weight: normal !important;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 35 Light', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/*-- END FONT ASSIGNMENTS --*/


/* INFOBAR - The Infobar is the navigation element at the top
used to navigate the subpages of the document and change the content
panel's content depending on the selected infoBar navigation element
--------------------------- */


/* infoBar Bottom Border */

#infoBar {
  background: #FFF;
  /*border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  max-width: 940px;
  text-align: center;
  /*display: table;*/
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* infoBar Bottom Border onHover or Active element*/

#infoBar a:hover,
#infoBar a.active {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #2889DE;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* infoBar Link Text */

#infoBar a {
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 35 Light', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1.4em;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* infoBar Link Text onHover */

#infoBar a:Hover {
  background: transparent;
  color: #2889DE;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 35 Light', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 1.4em;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* infoBar Active element */

#infoBar a.active {
  font-family: 'Avenir LT W01 65 Medium', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #infoBar a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 830px) {
  #infoBar a {
    padding: 1em 0.6em;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  #infoBar {
    display: none;
  }
}
/*-- END INFOBAR --*/


/* PAGE SECTIONS
--------------------------- */


/* Page Section Styling */

.page-section {
  background-position: center top;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  min-height: 200px;
  padding: 60px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 940px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Page Section - Header2 Styling */

.page-section h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


/* Page Section Paragraph Styling */

.page-section p {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /*margin: 10px 0 45px 0;*/
}


/* Foreword-Section-Top Styling */

.foreword-section-top {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 160px;
}


/* Foreword-Section-Top Header1 Styling*/

.foreword-section-top h1 {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 36px;
}


/* Foreword-Section-Top Paragraph Styling */

.foreword-section-top p {
  color: #4d4d4d;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.grid-100 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}


/* CONTENT PANELS
----------------------------- */
/* Capabilties Panel*/
#capabilities-panel {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
}

/*Tutorials Panel */
#tutorials-panel {
  max-width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:none;
}
.product-row {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  /*width: 100%; */
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
}

.product-box {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0.5%;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 24%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  .product-box {
    width: 48%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .product-box {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 95%;
  }
}

.product-box a {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.product-box a:hover .inner-box-padding {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.product-box .inner-box-padding {
  background-color: #007ac2;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -ms-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-box .inner-box-padding:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 87%;
}

.product-box h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.product-box.dark-text h3 {
  color: #333;
}

.product-box .capability-one {
  background-image: url('http://i64.tinypic.com/2mi16l1.png');
}

.product-box .capability-two {
  background-image: url('http://i68.tinypic.com/10gwm75.png');
}

.product-box .capability-three {
  background-image: url('http://i65.tinypic.com/5djxwh.png');
}

.product-box .capability-four {
  background-image: url('http://i67.tinypic.com/15e7hu8.png');
}

.product-box .tutorial-one {
  background-image: url('http://i68.tinypic.com/efhvfc.png');
}

.product-box .tutorial-two {
  background-image: url('http://i66.tinypic.com/50199u.png');
}

.product-box .tutorial-three {
  background-image: url('http://i63.tinypic.com/wvwcif.png');
}

.product-box .tutorial-four {
  background-image: url('http://i67.tinypic.com/1zp1or8.png');
}
/* END PRODUCT BOXES */
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

<!-- include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- INFO BAR -->
<div id="infoBar">
  <a href="/intro/capabilities" class="navItem active on" panel-id="capabilities-panel">Capabilities</a>

  <a href="/intro/tutorials" class="navItem" panel-id="tutorials-panel">Tutorials</a>

  <a href="/intro/use-cases" class="navItem">Use Cases</a>

  <a href="/intro/services" class="navItem">Services</a>

  <a href="/intro/security" class="navItem">Security</a>

  <a href="/intro/whats-new" class="navItem">What's New</a>

  <a href="/intro/request-access" class="navItem">Request Access</a>
</div>
<!-- END GIS INFO BAR -->

<!-- FOREWORD -->
<div class="page-section foreword-section-top">
  <h1>Some Cool Tagline</h1>
  <p>blah blah blah. We're so awesome. Now give us money.</p>
</div>

<!-- CAPABILITIES PANEL -->
<div id="capabilities-panel" class="panel">

  <!--  Capability One -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/capabilities/capability-one">
      <div class="inner-box-padding capability-one"></div>
      <h3>Capability 1</h3>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--  Capability Two box -->
  <div class="product-box dark-text">
    <a href="/capabilities/capability-two">
      <div class="inner-box-padding capability-two"></div>
      <h3>Capability 2</h3>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!--  Capability Three box -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/capabilities/capability-three">
      <div class="inner-box-padding capability-three"></div>
      <h3>Capability 3</h3>
    </a>
  </div>

  <!-- Capability Four box -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/capabilities/capability-four">
      <div class="inner-box-padding capability-four"></div>
      <h3>Capability 4</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END CAPABILITIES PANEL -->

<!-- TUTORIALS PANEL -->
<div id="tutorials-panel" class="panel">

  <!--  Tutorial One box -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/tutorials/tutorial-one">
      <div class="inner-box-padding tutorial-one"></div>
      <h3>Tutorial 1</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <!--  Tutorial Two box -->
  <div class="product-box dark-text">
    <a href="/tutorials/tutorial-two">
      <div class="inner-box-padding tutorial-two"></div>
      <h3>Tutorial 2</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <!--  Tutorial Three box -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/tutorials/tutorial-three">
      <div class="inner-box-padding tutorial-three"></div>
      <h3>Tutorial 3</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
  
  <!--  Tutorial Four box -->
  <div class="product-box">
    <a href="/tutorials/tutorial-four">
      <div class="inner-box-padding tutorial-four"></div>
      <h3>Tutorial 3</h3>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END TUTORIALS PANEL -->
```

Comment: check this http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-tabs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure that this might do something like you'd want.
There are more elegant pieces of code (not to mention that there should be loads of plugins) for this though, this is just out of the top of my head (dont use $.attr to find the corresponding panel etc).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".navItem").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('.navItem').removeClass("active").removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("active").addClass("on");
        var panel = $(this).attr('panel-id');

        $(".panel").hide();
        $("#"+panel).show();
    });
});
```

In order to use this script you need to import jQuery into your page though, which literally putting 1 line in your page (just google that).

You need to give every panel the class panel (i.e.  instead of just the 'id' attribute. This will allow for the $(".panel") to find all html that is in a

The `var panel = $(this).attr('panel-id');` line finds the panel belonging to the anchor the user clicked, as long as you add an attribute to each anchor containing the id of the corresponding panel as the value (e.g. `<a (..) panel-id="capabilities-panel">`)

=======

## Updated answer so OP can use vanilla javascript per his request.

```
   (function () {
        alert('hello');
        var links = document.getElementsByClassName("navItem");
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var link = links[i];
            link.addEventListener('click',function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                for(int k = 0; k < links; k++) {
                    links[k].className = "navItem";
                }
                event.target.className += " active on";


                var panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");
                for (j = 0; j < panels.length; j++) {
                    panels[j].style.display = 'none';
                }
                var panel_id = event.target.getAttribute("panel-id");
                document.getElementById(panel_id).style.display = 'block';
            });
        }
    })();
```

I haven't tested this so there's probably some syntactic errors here and there, and Im not too sure how one gets the sender element from a click event in vanilla javascript (though this shouldn't be too hard to google).
You need to put scripts in between `<script></script>` tags in order for your browser to recognize javascript.

Note how the number of lines and readability decreased by abandoning jQuery.

Hope this helps you!

Also, if this is just not working for you I recommend checking out the link the other guy posted under your question.

Comment: Thanks Glubus. Since this is my first foray into front-end web design, I'm trying to stick to pure HTML+CSS+JS and avoid using any plugins or helpers like jQuery if at all possible. I know that jQuery would probably make my life easier but I feel like I'll learn more faster by getting stuff done using the native functionalities and then move on to those helper libraries once I've got a good base to build off of. 

If you can think of something that doesn't require jQuery, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Ill update my answer in a second, but I do want to say that while jQuery does in fact make your life a whole lot easier, it does not prevent you from learning javascript at all, and most javascript found on the internet is using jQuery. So Im saying that I do recommend learning jQuery as well if you want to learn javascript (it's really not that hard to learn).

Comment: Thanks Glubus. I added the jQuery script from the Google CDN, then remove the href properties from the navItems and gave each navItem a new attribute, 'panel-id' and set it to the name of the associated panel to show. I then went to each of the panels (only two at this point) and assigned a new class 'panel' to each. Then I copied and pasted your script in but I'm not seeing any results.

Comment: I just updated it to pure javascript, though if you have that script put in, check out your console (shift + f5 in firefox) and see if the javascript is getting any errors.

Also check out my revised jQuery, the current script is not actually run because there is no event or function call triggering it. It needs to be activated by a $(document).ready event.

Comment: When I click on a navItem, it actually tries to follow the link. Those links don't even actually exist. When I removed them though, nothing would work.

Comment: That's because the browser has not linked your <a>'s to the script. Have you edited the script as per my changes? Did you surround the script with <script></script> tags?
Also, using href will in fact tell your browser to change the url in your url-bar, thus changing your location. the 'event.preventDefault()' part of the script will stop this if I'm not mistaken

Comment: I've updated the HTML to reflect the changes you suggested. I've also added jQuery, even though I don't think that matters. Thank you for your help, I'm going to keep tinkering with this but if you see something I'm missing, please let me know if you can.

Comment: Ok I tested it myself and through the console I found that I had some syntactic errors, like I said I would have. I've updated the jquery code that works for me with your html.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That was awesome! I noticed it didn't change the selected navBar Item's class to 'navItem active on' and change all the others to 'navItem'. I'm going to tinker a bit and see if I can make that work on my own...unless, you maybe, perhaps, might also know how to make that black magic work too...

Comment: Suuuuure I'll add that for you real quick too while Im at it.
I've also already updated the vanilla javascript to where it works like you want it to, without jquery.